# Windows 10 Movies & TV App - change arrow key functionality

Tags: windows, windows-10, video, youtube

**Context**:

In the Windows 10 "Movies & TV" program, when playing a video, hitting an arrow key does nothing by default. However, when the scrollbar under the video is selected, then arrow keys do have a functionality.

From experimentation with videos with different lengths, it seems that the right and left arrow keys, by default, skip forward or backward in the video by a length of time equal to `1/100` of the total length of the video. For example, a 50 minute video (3000 seconds) being played using the "Movies & TV" program would mean that pressing the right arrow key would move forward 30 seconds.

On YouTube, the arrow keys also only work when the scrollbar under the video is selected, but for YouTube videos, the right and left arrow keys correspond to jumps of 5 seconds forward or backward in the video being played, regardless of how long the video is.

I much prefer the 5 second increments, and there does not seem to be a built-in way to change how the arrow keys work in the settings menu of the "Movies & TV" program.

---

**My question**:

Is there some way to change some configuration file for the Windows 10 "Movies & TV" program so that the arrow keys would go forwards or backwards by a fixed number of seconds, regardless of video length?

Or would it be possible to achieve this functionality using some kind of script running while I have "Movies & TV" open?

Or should I just download and use a different video playback software?

---

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find an anser?